# adding multiple ViewFlipper in Activity

Tags: android, viewflipper

I want to add multiple ViewFlipper dynamically but the problem is on the gesture listener which detect only the last added one,

```
        for (int i = 0; i < _Array.size(); i++) {
        mViewFlipper = new ViewFlipper(mContext);
        for (int j = 0; j < getContent().size(); j++) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
            if (j / 2 == 0)
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
            else
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
            mViewFlipper.addView(img);
        }
        mViewFlipper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
        frame.addView(mViewFlipper);
    }
```

detector is the SimpleOnGestureListener.

when I try to swipe any viewFlipper only the last one swipes.

Comment: In your on touch method, do `return detector.onTouchEvent(event)`. That will back propagate the actual detection instead of always eating it.

Comment: well i did it but nothing happened, no swiping at all.

Comment: i added some Logs in the SwipeGestureDetector methodes but it's not showing any, it's like the touch is not consumed at al